# when there is no internet connection the URLSession returning NSURLErrorTimedOut instead of NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet iOS 14

Tags: objective-c, ios14

When i execute code with my internet connection disabled. In iOS13 the completionBlock gets called immediately and I have this error

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline."
```

But, when I execute exactly the same code under iOS14 the completion block gets called after one minute (the timeout) and the error that i have is different

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."
```

How to get error.Code=-1009 in iOS14, Thanks in advance.